# strange crash in garbage-collected Core Data program

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data

I have a garbage-collected CoreData app, which is used by a few of my friends.  It's a fairly standard app where the Core Data entries are shown on table views.

Some of them report the following mysterious crash reports, triggered by a change in the sort criteria of the table view.

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: objCType
objc[1415]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff885bf10a objc_msgSend + 22
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82a80f91 -[NSNumber compare:] + 102
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82aa9c9a _NSCompareObject + 75
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82ae1ab9 _NSSortFunctionMany + 626
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87f24419 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 409
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87f242d8 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 88
....
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87f242d8 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 88
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87f240cd CFSortIndexes + 317
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87f56a23 CFMergeSortArray + 147
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82aa99f3 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 572
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82ae162a -[NSMutableArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortUsingDescriptors:] + 440
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84f06ad8 -[NSArrayController _sortObjects:] + 337
21  com.yujitach.spires             0x00000001000225e0 -[IncrementalArrayController arrangeObjects:] + 194
```

Here, `IncrementalArrayController` is a subclass of `NSArrayController`. I don't understand why `arrangeObjects:` of an Objective-C array, returned from CoreData, leads to a crash.

Is it related to the multi-threaded-ness of my program? I follow what the documents say: a MOC per thread, and I don't pass managed objects across threads, only managed object IDs.

I'd appreciate if anybody could suggest me how to debug it. e.g. I'd like to see which object is causing the crash on `objc_msgSend`. How can I track it down?

If you need the source code, it's available via `bzr`:

```
$ bzr branch http://www.sns.ias.edu/~yujitach/spires/code/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in early versions of 10.6 that involved sorting very large arrays in garbage collected apps.   A fix is in an update.

Comment: Do you mean in a forthcoming update? This bug is on 10.6.4.  Hopefully the fix is in 10.6.5 ...